# Outlook VBA variable into HTML Body

Tags: html, vba, variables

I created an Macro in MS Outlook for an email. The user inputs an answer to a question which results in a variable storing that data as a string. An email is then generated in HTML with a hyperlink containing that variable. I can't seem to figure out how to concatenate the variable "strTrackingNumber" into the complete hyperlink. Any suggestions?

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestFile

Dim strTrackingNumber as String
strTrackingNumber = InputBox("Please input the Tracking Number")
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 With objMsg
  .To = "mickey.smith@surfer.com"
  .CC = ""
  .BCC = ""
  .Subject = "Forecast"
  .Categories = ""
  .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML ' send HTML message
  .HTMLBody = "<style> body{color:black;font-family:Arial;font-size: 12pt;}" & _
"<HTML><body>Dear Member,<br><br>&emsp;The following document is ready for your review."<a href= 'http://www.bluewave.com/' & strTrackingNumber>Tracking & strTrackingNumber.</a></body>

.Display
End With
Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Output link should look like this: http://www.bluewave.com/Tracking Number
e.g. http://www.bluewave.com/RA-15-30922

Comment: Would help to provide an example of what the final link should look like.  It's not clear from your code.

Comment: Thanks, I can see from your answer the quotation marks were missing in some places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.HTMLBody = "<style> body{color:black;font-family:Arial;font-size: 12pt;} </style>" & _
      "<HTML><body>Dear Member,<br><br>&emsp;" & _
      "The following document is ready for your review. " & _
     "<a href= 'http://www.bluewave.com/" & strTrackingNumber & "'>Tracking " & _
      strTrackingNumber & ".</a></body>"
```